# Как через php вывести видео на сайте?

Tags: php, opencart

Что мы имеем:
Интернет-магазин сделанные на OpenCart.
Видео на стороннем ресурсе.
Картинка на стороннем ресурсе.

Что нужно сделать:
Нужно чтобы видео и картинка выводилось во всех товарах. Реализовать это нужно через php, но... Если видео или картинка отсутствует по ссылке, тогда должно быть просто пустая область без всяких пометок что видео или изображение отсутствует.

Вопрос:
Как данное реализовать в каком виде и файле на OpenCart прописать?

Comment: В смысле по ссылке? проще не добавлять битые ссылки (это даже куда разумнее...)... а если нету видео или картинке, то просто хранить пустоту в поле БД... и когда это все выводите, обычную проверку сделайте если это не пустота, то вывести видео или картинку (или что там у вас...)

Comment: Спасибо! Пример кода можно?

Comment: я не работал с OpenCart, по этому не могу сказать наверняка, как будет правильно реализовать это. Могу только посоветовать обратится к официально документации, и почитать раздел о дополнительных полях.

Comment: Где лежит видео файл?